# How can I take a larger screenshot on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-capture

I would like to take a screenshot of an entire web page in Mobile Safari, not just the part that's visible on the screen. I'm running iOS 5 on an iPhone 4, but I'm pretty sure this functionality isn't built in anywhere. What app or trick do I need?

Comment: Are you open to a solution that uses the print functionality (with or without reader)? I'm fairly certain unmodified iOS can't by itself print to a PDF (but let's see if anyone can answer in the next few days) If I needed this today, [Printopia by Ecamm](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/) lets your mac receive any iOS print and convert it to various file formats.

Comment: Not providing this as an answer, as you specifically say you want to use the iphone, but changing your user agent on normal safari then printing as pdf would do the trick.

Comment: I changed your title. I hope that's what you meant. Let me know if it isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Natively available in iOS 13 and later

This functionality is now built into iOS 13 by Apple. Safari running in iOS 13 lets you screenshot the entire webpage as a single continuous image.

To do that, open the desired webpage in Safari, and simply take a screenshot [as you would normally do](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT200289) on your device, and tap on the thumbnail shown immediately shown towards the bottom left.

You'll be presented with two options at the top in a segmented control:

- Screen

  and
- Full Page

[image] [image]

With the Full Page item selected, tap on the Share icon in the top right to share the capture via desired medium. AirDropping it for instance, exports a single PDF file, which can be easily exported into a desired image format.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm installing iOS 13 now and will play with this. Do you know if it works in apps other than Safari?

Comment: @hairboat Works exclusively in Safari as of this writing. On an unrelated note, you may wish to hold on for iOS 13.1 which releases tomorrow. iOS 13 is widely reported to be way buggier for a public release.

Answer (score 4):

[Webshot Free](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webshot-free/id392541270?mt=8) can do this (there's a 99¢ ad-free version too). It's supposed to let you just change http:// to webshot:// and it will open the same URL in in the app. That didn't work, but cut+paste did.

There may be other apps which are better for certain needs, depending on what you want to actually do with the page. If you just want a JPG or PNG of it, Webshot Free works fine.

If you are trying to save a page for reading later, [iCab Mobile](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icab-mobile-web-browser/id308111628?mt=8) ($2, universal) will let you save a .webarchive or a .pdf file. [Note: the print to pdf function is actually provided by 3rd party webapps, but it's integrated into iCab].

There are a variety of "Print to PDF" apps in the app store, [PrintBureau](http://itunes.apple.com/app/pns/id363371015), seems to be one of the better ones (and is universal).

Comment: Webshot! Webshot webshot webshot webshot.

Answer (score 3):

This question has been [asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188534/how-to-capture-entire-webpage-in-iphone-safari).

[Webpage Capture](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webpage-capture/id348797820?mt=8) ($2.39, [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85afdTIW_eU), [confirmed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188534/how-to-capture-entire-webpage-in-iphone-safari)) or [Website Screenshot](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/website-screenshot/id437683442?mt=8#) ($0.99) should do the trick.

*I have not tested any of them.*

---

As a side note: since Safari for Mac itself doesn't do full page export*, it really doesn't come as a surprise there's no way to do so on iOS.

*yes, of course you can print as PDF, but that's completely different from saving a full-dimensioned, not-paginated, not-styled-for-print version of the website (for which a third-party app such as LittleSnapper is necessary)

Answer (score 1):

[Tailor](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/tailor-screenshot-stitching/id926653095) (App Store link) is a free app that does this extremely easily by detecting sequential screenshots in your iOS device’s Photos and stitching them together automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal obviously, but if you need a shot of the page exactly as it appears on the phone, your best bet is to scroll around the page, taking a series of screen shots and manually stitch them together on a PC.

Printing to a PC as a PDF is an alright idea, as is setting your desktop Safari to send the iPhone user-agent, but neither will give you perfect renderings of what it looks like on the iPhone, often there will be substantial formatting differences.

Answer (score 0):

[Webpage Capture for iPhone | iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/webpage-capture/id348797820?mt=8)

From the iTunes description:

> Webpage Capture enables you to take a screenshot of the complete
>   webpage you are browsing. You can then save it, email it or share it
>   on Social networks like Facebook, Twitter and Flickr. Saving as PDF
>   enables you to archive your files and access them for off-line reading
>   and for record-keeping.
>
> This version also enables you to export pdf files to iBooks,
>   Evernote...and any other app you have for reading pdf files.
>
> The app captures the complete webpage whether visible or not as an
>   image instead of HTML. This is useful for keeping track of pages
>   visited, keeping a log of dynamic pages, for storing information (eBay
>   auctions, digital magazine, digital newspapers...) or for later
>   reading or for sharing with somebody somewhere that cannot access a
>   webpage.
>
> The screenshot can be saved on the device itself and can also be
>   transferred via iTunes File Share.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

1. Launch Mobile Safari on devices running iOS5.
2. Type the URL of the website of interest.
3. After the web page is done loading, touch the gray Reader "button"
   to the right of the URL address.[image: Mobile Safari web browser]
4. Mobile Safari is now in "Reader" mode (note the purple text color), select the [image] icon and choose "Mail this Article". Provide a valid email address.  The entire web page
   (photos, text, etc) including portions not visible or not displayed
   will be appended into the email message you're composing.[image: Mobile Safari web browser in Reader mode]
5. Launch your email browser to verify. This is necessary because some websites may not render properly because they use frames, etc. Furthermore, the Reader function will not capture animated gifs, Flash animation, movies, and sounds.

Comment: Huh? Just tried on my iPhone, the mailed article is the Reader view, not at all the original website. Plus, it only works if the website is compatible with the Reader mode!

Comment: Matti, agree with your comment that "…only works if the website is compatible with the Reader mode!" which is why I clearly stated on 5 that "some websites may not render properly…". This is the closest (without jail breaking) that I know of to capture the entire webpage (though not as it originally looks).

Comment: Ah, but I think the OP is interested in capturing the _look_ of the page rather than its contents, don't you agree? At least, that's what the term “screenshot” means to me :-S